%matplotlib widget not rendering plots
I am doing some remote development using VScodes's remote-ssh extension. My VScode is local. When I open a .ipynb file, I am able to connect it to a remote conda environment no problem, after installing ipykernel. I also have ipympl installed and ipywidgets, all installed via conda.
My issue is that I cannot seem to get matplotlib widgets to render correctly. For example, executing this cell:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 20, 100)));

Produces a plot like normal. However, when I insert %matplotlib widget after my import statements, the plot renders a slim rectangle: See image
I can change the "presentation" to be an img/png again, and that works, but I would like it working with the widget backend, since I have other plots that are interactive.
I have tried a plethora of solutions, such as re-installing the VScode juptyer extension, using different matplotlib backends (notebook, ipympl, Agg, qt), enabling x11 forwarding on my ssh connection. None have worked. The thing that is driving me nuts is that I see a ton of posts (like this) with very similar issues, but none of those proposed solutions work for me.
I am still less than a week new to remote-ssh development, so I was thinking maybe there is something related to that causing an issue that I am unaware of (although, reproducing the code with a local interpreter yeilds the same behavior). I am brand new to these magic commands and widgets associated with matplotlib in .ipynb files, so I could also just be misunderstanding something there too. There are no errors in my terminal instances to report back, at least as far as I can see right now.
I will add the vscode tag, since notebook functionality seems to be specific to the IDE, in general. Any help would be appreciated.
